# Read text from stream char by char

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, f#, stream

I've started learning F# and functional programming in general, but the code I wrote doesn't seems to be really *functional*. Could you take a look and say how to make it more as it should be in functional programming?

```
type internal CsvReader(source : Stream) = 

    // input stream
    let stream = source

    // reader
    let mutable reader : StreamReader = new StreamReader(source)

    [<Literal>]
    let bufferSize = 1000

    // currently processed line
    let mutable buffer : char[] = Array.zeroCreate bufferSize

    // current position
    let mutable currentPosition : int = bufferSize

    // end of file
    let mutable EndOfFile : bool = false

    // loads new chunk of data from file to buffer
    let UpdateBuffer() : bool =
        match reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) with
        | 0 -> false
        | _ -> true

    // initialization method
    let Initialize() =
        let pos = source.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        if not (pos = 0L) then raise(Exception("sdf"))
        ()

    // read one char from stream
    let rec GetChar(eat : bool) : (bool * char) = 
        let position = currentPosition
        match position with
        | 1000 -> 
            match UpdateBuffer() with
            | false ->
                EndOfFile <- true
                (false, Char.MinValue)
            | true -> currentPosition <- 0; GetChar(eat)
        | _ -> 
            let item = System.Convert.ToInt32(buffer.[position])
            match item with
            | 0 -> (false, Char.MinValue)
            | _ ->
                match eat with
                | true ->
                    currentPosition <- currentPosition + 1;
                    (true, buffer.[position])
                | false -> 
                    (true, buffer.[position])

    // default constructor logic
    do
        if Utils.IsNull source then raise(ArgumentNullException("source"))
        if not source.CanRead then raise(ArgumentException("source"))
        if not source.CanSeek then raise(ArgumentException("source"))

        Initialize()

        ()

    // parameterless constructor
    // always throws ArgumentNullException
    private new() = CsvReader(null)

    // just for testing
    member x.PublicGetChar = GetChar
```

Right now the only think it does it stream content of `Stream` char by char by `PublicGetChar` method. I wrote UT to make sure it works:

```
[<TestClass>]
type CsvReaderTests() = 

    let GetStringStream(input : string) : Stream = 
        let stream = new MemoryStream()
        let writer = new StreamWriter(stream)
        ignore(writer.Write(input))
        writer.Flush()
        stream.Position <- 0L
        stream :> Stream

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestMethod1 () = 
        let input = "test"
        let reader = new CsvReader(GetStringStream(input))
        let chars = seq { while fst(reader.PublicGetChar(false)) do yield snd(reader.PublicGetChar(true)) }
        let output = (new System.String(chars |> Array.ofSeq))
        input |> should equal output
```

Main concerns I have about the code:

- usage of `match`/`with`
- a lot of `mutable` stuff within `CsvReader` type
- if I had to write it in C# it would look really similar :D

That's the very first F# code I've ever written, so be polite, please :)

Comment: What's the point of all this code, why won't you just use `StreamReader.Read()`?

Comment: @svick Calling `Read` would require file access every time you call it. With this code you read from file in chunks, which should be faster.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. `StreamReader` already has an internal buffer. Anyway, whenever you do something that “should be faster”, you should really measure that it actually is faster.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely measure that if it was production code. It's not :) I'm trying to learn f# and that's the only reason I wrote this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your first F# code isn't too bad. I've made some small simplifications to streamline your code a bit and take advantage of some built-in F# functions:

```
type internal CsvReader(source : Stream) = 

    // input stream
    let stream = source

    // reader
    let mutable reader : StreamReader = new StreamReader(source)

    [<Literal>]
    let bufferSize = 1000

    // currently processed line
    let mutable buffer : char[] = Array.zeroCreate bufferSize

    // current position
    let mutable currentPosition = bufferSize

    // end of file
    let mutable EndOfFile = false

    // loads new chunk of data from file to buffer
    let UpdateBuffer() : bool =
        reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) <> 0

    // initialization method
    let Initialize() =
        let pos = source.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        if not (pos = 0L) then
            invalidOp "sdf"

    // read one char from stream
    let rec GetChar(eat : bool) : (bool * char) = 
        let position = currentPosition
        match position with
        | 1000 ->
            match UpdateBuffer() with
            | false ->
                EndOfFile <- true
                false, Char.MinValue
            | true ->
                currentPosition <- 0
                GetChar eat
        | _ -> 
            match int buffer.[position] with
            | 0 ->
                false, Char.MinValue
            | _ ->
                match eat with
                | true ->
                    currentPosition <- currentPosition + 1
                    true, buffer.[position]
                | false -> 
                    true, buffer.[position]

    // default constructor logic
    do
        if Utils.IsNull source then
            nullArg "source"
        if not source.CanRead then
            invalidArg "source" "The source stream cannot be read from."
        if not source.CanSeek then
            invalidArg "source" "The source stream does not support seeking."

        Initialize()

    // parameterless constructor
    // always throws ArgumentNullException
    private new() = CsvReader(null)

    // just for testing
    member x.PublicGetChar = GetChar
```

One thing you'd definitely want to add (if this were production code) -- this class would ideally implement the `IDisposable` interface so you can properly close and release the resources associated with the `StreamReader` you use internally.